# RSPEC+Capybara + poltergeist :How to send keys to windows pop up dialgue opened from browser

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I want to send keys to FileUpload window using Capybara . JavaScript Driver : Poltergeist.

UI :
[File Upload Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Nhx.png)

```
click_button 'BrowseBtn'
sleep(1)
popup = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
page.within_window(popup) do
page.find('body').native.send_key(pathToInvalidTestLicenseFile.to_s)
page.find('body').native.send_key(:Enter)
end
```

I am not sure of the following things.
a) How do I verify whether popup dialog got opened after clicking browse button? I have taken screen shot after clicking browse button , but in the screen shot browse window doesnot come?Is it expected?
b) How do I verify whether popup diaglog has received the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send_keys to the system file selection dialog, you have to call `#attach_file` with identifiers for the file input element. Given html like

```
<input type='file' id='my_file_input' name='my_file_input>
```

You would do something like

```
attach_file('my_file_input', pathToInvalidTestLicenseFile)
```

in your test.  The one issue that comes up a lot with file fields is that they are often hidden on the page, and replaced with another element that is stylable.  In that case you need to use execute_script to modify the css of the file input to make it visible before calling `attach_file`.  The css that you need to change would depend on how the element is hidden, however if it was just set to opacity: 0 then something like

```
page.execute_script("$('#my_file_input').css('opacity', 1);")
page.attach_file('my_file_input', pathToInvalidTestLicenseFile)
```

should work (assuming your using jQuery on your page - swap for standard DOM methods if not).

=========================

As a second issue - when you do have code that opens another window, rather than using driver specific methods and manual sleeps you should be using something like

```
popup = window_opened_by { click_button 'BrowseBtn' }
```

This doesn't work in this case because you're not opening a new browser window, you're triggering the opening of a system dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful detailed explanation. I initially also tried calling attach_file but as you have mentioned since it is hidden  it didnot work. So, I have changed my view to make it display out of view by setting margin as -9999 . Your solution looks more neat than what I did. I will try your solution and let you kow, Once again thanks.